# 「キャッシュ」と「閲覧履歴」の違い。「キャッシュ無効化」や「キャッシュ削除」はどうやって確認？

Tags: google-chrome

**最終的にやりたいこと**
・「Google Chrome」で「キャッシュ無効化」したい
・難しければ「キャッシュ削除」したい

※頻繁に使用するので1クリックで処理したい
※デベロッパーツールは表示確認の邪魔になるので使用したくない

---

**知りたいこと**
・「キャッシュ無効化」あるいは「キャッシュ削除」出来たことを確認するには、どうすれば良いでしょうか？

---

**試したこと**
・「起動オプション」や「拡張機能」を試しているのですが、期待した結果を得られません

---

**下記認識は誤りですか？**
・「閲覧履歴が削除された」ら「キャッシュ削除」
・「閲覧履歴に追加されなかった」ら「キャッシュ無効化」

・「閲覧履歴」と「キャッシュ」は異なるもの？
・あるいは「閲覧履歴」の一部が「キャッシュ」？？

Comment: `chrome://view-http-cache/` でキャッシュされているURLが確認できます。なのでこれが空になっているかどうかでコンテンツのキャッシュがされているか確認できると思います。

Comment: また、ウインドウズの場合、chrome のキャッシュフォルダが`C:\Users\ユーザー名\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data` なので、そちらを確認してもいいかも。 このフォルダの内容を削除するようなスクリプトを作成して実行するようにしたらいいかも。（自己責任）

Comment: 「キャッシュ」を確認できるURLがちゃんとあるのですね。物凄く勘違いしていました

Comment: ちなみに`chrome://cache/` を使うとキャッシュされているファイルの確認もできます。

Comment: ウインドウズなのでフォルダ内容を確認してみましたが、内容難しかったです。質問した時点では、起動ブラウザ毎にキャッシュを保持しているのかと思っていたのですが、ウインドウズユーザ単位で保持していることが分かり、ちょっとびっくりしました。参考になりました

Comment: 「シークレットウインドウを開く」でブラウズする場合、キャッシュがされていない状態で始まり、終了時に削除されると思うので通常これで充分かと思いますが。

Comment: 「シークレットウインドウ」でブラウズしてもキャッシュされることがあるのですが、「シークレットウインドウ」を起動している時、「通常ウインドウ」も一緒に開いていることが原因ということは考えられるでしょうか？　あるいはそもそも「シークレットウインドウ」でキャッシュされること自体があり得ない？？

Comment: 読み込んだ内容がキャッシュされるという意味でしたらそれはあると思います。起動オプションでキャッシュの設定はされているんですよね？

Comment: 「シークレットウインドウ」について思わず質問したのですが、よく考えてみれば当初の質問内容とは厳密には異なるため、まずは自分で確認してみることにします。ありがとうございました

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 閲覧履歴とは、ブラウザーで過去に閲覧したことがあるURLのリストです。
- キャッシュとは、ブラウザーで過去に閲覧した際に、URLに対してコンテンツを保存したものなので、コンテンツのリストです。

ですので、キャッシュを保持したまま閲覧履歴を削除することも可能です。その場合、閲覧したことはないものの、いざ閲覧する際には既に保持しているコンテンツを流用することが可能です。

> 「Google Chrome」で「キャッシュ無効化」したい

コンテンツ側でキャッシュ不可を通知した場合、Google Chromeは指示に従いキャッシュしません。ですので、`Cache-Control: no-store`の応答を返すことを検討してください。

[HTTP キャッシュ](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=ja)

Comment: 「キャッシュ削除」したが「閲覧履歴は残っている」ということはあり得るでしょうか？

Comment: @re9 さん、当然可能です。

Comment: なるほど。やはりそうなのですね。物凄く勘違いしていたことにようやく気が付きました…

Answer (score 1):

この[リンク先](http://chrome.half-moon.org/43.html#b32d6703)によると、

> ディスクキャッシュフォルダの場所を変更します。指定したフォルダの中にCacheフォルダとMedia
>   Cacheフォルダが必要に応じて作成されます。(通常はユーザデータフォルダ内に作成されます)
>   RAMディスクにキャッシュを移動したい場合などに有効です。
>
> --disk-cache-dir="R:\Chrome Cache"　RドライブのルートにあるChrome
>   Cacheフォルダをディスクキャッシュフォルダに指定します。
>
> パスに半角スペースが含まれる場合は、例のように=の右側をダブルクオーテーション(")で囲む必要があります。
>   フォルダが存在しない場合は、上位フォルダも含めて自動的に作成されます。ただし存在しないドライブ（上記の例では「R:」の部分）を指定した場合はフォルダが作成されず、既定のキャッシュフォルダも使用されません。

ということなので、
**無効なドライブからのパスを指定することによって、キャッシュが使用されない**
らしい（未確認）ので
「キャッシュの無効化」になると思います。

またこの項目の下にある
--disk-cache-size=NUM
--media-cache-size=NUM
で1を指定することでキャッシュのサイズが１バイトになるので実質無効化できるかと思います。
(未確認)

Comment: 「無効なドライブ指定」「サイズ1指定」について、私が試した限りでは何れもうまくいきませんでした。ショートカットから起動後,ブラウジングしていく度に「chrome://cache/」内容が追加されていきます。今回質問した件については、chrome拡張機能を使用すると「chrome://cache/」が削除されることが分かったので、それを使用していこうと思います

Comment: 情報が古かったんですかね。すみません。